# Why does my WPF tooltips and menu items display at the top/left of the screen

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, wpf-4.0

I have a few buttons in my wpf application, as well as a few Menu's with menu items. The problem is that whenever I hover over my buttons, the tooltip is being displayed at the upper left corner of my screen, and when I click on a menu, the menu items are also displayed on the upper left corner of the screen.

I am currently using Visual Studio 2010, and I am running Windows 7 64bit.

How can I resolve this?

If this would help, here is a sample of a control template used on a button:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CompileButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Grid ToolTip="Run all test cases" Cursor="Hand">
            <Ellipse x:Name="ell" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Compile.png"/>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="ell" Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem, not on all machines but on some. It happend when the window was maximized, suddenly all popups (tooltips, comboboxes) appeared at the top left corner. The fix we used was to change the horizontal scrollbar behavior of all scrollviewers. If you had set it to auto, and have a very specific width, there seems to be a bug in the layouting process causing all popups to show this behavior. So we always show the scrollbars and the bug was gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can set where the Tooltip will be placed by adding

```
<Grid ToolTip.Placement="Mouse" ... />
```

Among a few others.

[Tooltip Placement MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip.placement.aspx)

[PlacementMode Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.placementmode.aspx)

It seems like you aren't the only person getting this error, there are a few work arounds in this thread on [the MSDN social site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/545461b5-cf62-48e2-bcfb-2e872ecea639/wpf-tooltips-and-comboboxes-are-in-top-left-corner)

Comment: This is not working either.  I think there might be something in my styles that is somehow casuing this effect.  If I try a create a new project, and just for example use: <Button tooltip="Example"/> it displays correctly.

Comment: @akemp Try it using the ToolTipService.Placement instead.